# what class loader is used?

Tags: java, classloader, contextclassloader

I have several questions regarding to class loaders.

```
Class.forName("class.name");
```

and

```
....
NotYetLoadedClass cls = new NotYetLoadedClass();
.....
```

What class loaders will be used in each case? For the first case I assume class loader that was used to load class in which method code is executing. And in the second case I assume thread context class loader.

In case I am wrong, a small explanation is appreciated.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29 for the first case (your assumption is correct). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both use the current `ClassLoader`. As DNA correctly points out, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29 states that `Class.forName()` uses the current class loader. A little experiment shows that a class loaded for instantiation using the `new` statement also uses the current `ClassLoader`:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new MyClassLoader());
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.printClassLoader();
    }

    public static class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader
    {
        public MyClassLoader()
        {
            super();
        }

        public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader parent)
        {
            super(parent);
        }
    }
}



public class SomeClass
{
    public void printClassLoader()
    {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
}
```

In `Test` we set the current's thread ContextClassLoader to some custom `ClassLoader` and then instantiate an object of class `SomeClass`. In `SomeClass` we print out the current thread's ContextClassLoader and the `ClassLoader` that loaded this object's class. The result is

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3326b249
test.Test$MyClassLoader@3d4b7453
```

indicating that the current `ClassLoader` (`sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader`) was used to load the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "the current `ClassLoader`"?

Comment: @jameshfisher "the defining class loader of the current class"

Comment: What do you mean by "the current class"? Lexical scope?

Comment: "he "current class" is the class whose method is being executed.  That class was loaded by some ClassLoader, and that ClassLoader is first in line when loading new classes by either the techniques in the question