# Could you please explain a code snippet in DriverManager.class related to ClassLoader

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

The following code is from `java.sql.DriverManager`:

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url,String user, String password)    {
    // Gets the classloader of the code that called this method, may 
    // be null.
    ClassLoader callerCL = DriverManager.getCallerClassLoader();
    return (getConnection(url, info, callerCL));
 }
```

My first question is why the result value of `DriverManager.getCallerClassLoader();` may be null? I think the caller Class should be user's own Class, and it is usually **AppClassLoader**.

The subsequence of above code `getConnection(url, info, callerCL)`, and the method body contains following code snippet.

```
if(callerCL == null) {
    callerCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
}
```

What's `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` for? I have gone through the document and can't understand it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question,

*why the result value of `DriverManager.getCallerClassLoader();` may be null?*

It because, if you see the way its defined in class `DriverManager`

```
/* Returns the caller's class loader, or null if none */
    private static native ClassLoader getCallerClassLoader();
```

Its a native method and null value can returned.

To answer your second question:

What's `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` for?

**Every thread has a classloader associated with it**. If the thread is a main thread then the class loader associated with it a System Class Loader.

Many a times you create  an object by one class loader and this object can be potentially used by a thread started by some other class loader. So `getContextClassLoader()` lets you access a class loader which not the one which loaded the object and can access the resources available to the Thread's class loader.

[Here is another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader) on the same forum elaborating more on the same topic.