# Read an xml file from a servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I can't load correctly a file xml from my servlet:
that's the code:

```
       try{

           DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
           DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
           Document doc = db.parse("db.xml");
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
           out.print("File Not Found!");
   }
```

the db.xml is inside the classes folder with the class and the java file...

Comment: If it's on the classpath you need to use `ClassLoader#GetResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Document doc = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("db.xml"); ???

Comment: Read the javadoc for `Class#getResourceAsStream()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the XML file in the root folder of the war file, you can read it using the [real path](http://www.mkyong.com/javaee/the-method-getrealpathstring-from-the-type-servletrequest-is-deprecated/) for the context application folder.

```
String contextPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

In another way, you can use the [context class loader in a multi-module environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader):

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
Document doc = db.parse(classloader.getResourceAsStream(contextPath+ "/db.xml"));
```

In some environments, the additional slash is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `getResourceAsStream()`

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("db.xml"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        out.print("File Not Found!");
    }
```

Comment: it says File Not Found... the db.xml is on the root folder of my project and also inside the classes folder... is it correct?

Comment: Give it a go with other paths such as "/db.xml". Trial and error will get you everywhere...

Comment: And you're sure the resource is on your classpath?

Comment: it is on app/WEB-INF/classes/

Comment: and also I have a copy on app/