# Use of Thread's ContextClassLoader

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader

In the lines below:

These are the two methods of getting the classloaders

> 1) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
>
> 2) getClass().getClassLoader();

Would anybody please explain me the difference between these two.

Also my second question is when do we use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()

I have already refered some post on StackOverflow regarding the same, but didn't find the fundamental answer.

I have seen the answer of the question you suggested.

[Difference between thread's context class loader and normal classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader)

Thread context classloaders provide a back door around the classloading delegation scheme. 
 Take JNDI for instance: its guts are implemented by bootstrap classes in rt.jar (starting with J2SE 1.3), but these core JNDI
 classes may load JNDI providers implemented by independent vendors and
 potentially deployed in the application's -classpath. This scenario
 calls for a parent classloader (the primordial one in this case) to
 load a class visible to one of its child classloaders (the system one,
 for example). Normal J2SE delegation does not work, and **the workaround
 is to make the core JNDI classes use thread context loaders**, thus
 effectively "tunneling" through the classloader hierarchy in the
 direction opposite to the proper delegation.

> As it is suggested that the workaround is to make the core JNDI
>   classes use thread context loaders, I didn't understand how this helps
>   in this case.
>
> We want to load the implementation vendor classes using parent
>   classloader but they are not visible to parent classloader. So how can
>   we load them using parent, even if we set this parent classloader in
>   context classloader of thread.

Please suggest

Comment: @RohitJain I have added my comments. would you please remove the duplicate scenario?

Comment: A good link for your understanding http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-06/01-qa-0606-load.html