# getResourceAsStream working on jUnit, but not on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, junit

I have a third party library that works with jUnit, but does not once deployed to tomcat. Digging into the code, I can see it fails here:

```
final String path = "/api-version.dat";
final InputStream stream = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

The api-version.dat is located on jUnit test, but doing the same on Tomcat results in `NullPointerException` due to Tomcat unable to get the api-version file. This file exist and it is located inside the third party jar. What I have tried so far:

- Check jar is imported into Tomcat: It is inside WEB-INF/lib, so I would say yes
- Create an api-version.dat file and place it on my resources folder (I use maven). Does not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Print out `System.getProperty("java.class.path");` and check if the lib is on there.

Comment: What is the path of the api-version.dat file inside the JAR file? Is the JAR file located in WEB-INF/lib or a sub-directory of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Java EE enviroments use:

```
final InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread()
                                 .getContextClassLoader()
                                 .getResourceAsStream(path);
```

See more in [*Difference between thread's context class loader and normal classloader*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader).

Comment: Thanks for this one, however, it is a third party library and I'm not able to modify it. Does it mean I cannot deploy it to a JEE environment?

Comment: Right. Is it possible to inherit the class and override the method? Another way would be to inject a new method in the class, but it's complicated.

Comment: I have overridden the class, and that does not work either. It works if I return a String as the version, however I would like a cleaner way.