# Tomcat class loader on servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, reflection, annotations

In my tomcat servlet, I am referencing a third party jar in which all annotations are loaded by `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().` (JDK library)

Currently, I am not able to get annotations properly within my servlet because I think servlet itself is loaded by a different class loader.

How do I work around this issue? Since it is a 3rd-party jar, I can't just change the call to use a different class loader.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

See also:

- [Difference between thread's context class loader and normal classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader).