# MyBatis looking for xml files in Tomcat directory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, mybatis

I'm testing a web application with Eclipse + Tomcat, Eclipse deploys the web application files and launches Tomcat, and the application runs fine. But when MyBatis is trying to open it's XML configuration files, it looks for them in

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\persistence\db\oracle.xml
```

instead of the correct place:

```
C:\workspace\mywebapp\src\persistence\db\oracle.xml
```

Where is MyBatis supposed to look for XML files?

**EDIT:**

This is where I specify the relative path:

```
String cfgFile = "persistence/db/oracle.xml";
Reader reader  = Resources.getResourceAsReader(cfgFile);
session.put(db, new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader));
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using for load the MyBatis's XML?

Comment: Are you using maven (`pom.xml`)?

Comment: No, I'm not using maven

Answer (score 1):

`Resources.getResourceAsReader` looks files in classpath. For web application running in tomcat classpath  consist of `WEB-INF/classes` and all jars from `WEB-INF/lib` and tomcat folders like `$TOMCAT_HOME\lib`.

The issue you encounter most probably is caused by the fact that `oracle.xml` file is not added to deployment. It looks like `c:\workspace\myweapp\src` is not among source folder of eclipse project so eclipse doesn't copy files from it to the folder which is deployed to tomcat. Depending on your existing project structure you may need to create subfolder in src and add `persistence` with all subfolders there. This will allow you to avoid clash if some subfolder of src is already a source folder in eclipse. I would recommend to use [maven project structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

```
src
   main
      * java  
          you java source code here organized by package
      * resources
          persistence
```

I marked folders which should be added as source folder to eclipse with `*`.

Please note that it is not correct to say that `C:\workspace\mywebapp\src\persistence\db\oracle.xml` is a correct place to search for it. After you create a war to deploy it on production this path most probably will not be available at your production server. What you really need is to include `persistence\db\oracle.xml` to the war in appropriate place (under `WEB-INF/classes`).

Comment: Analyzing your answer I realized that there was a uppercase/lowercase problem in my cfgFile variable. Such a problem with Java source files is detected by Eclipse and it shows the red error icon, but not with XML files as in this case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need another class loader <sup>**1**</sup>. Try this:

```
String cfgFile = "persistence/db/oracle.xml";
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
Reader reader  = Resources.getResourceAsReader(classloader, cfgFile);
```

---

*Notes*

1. See [Difference between thread's context class loader and normal classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader) and you may want to see the code of `org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources`. You find it [here](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/io/Resources.java).