# ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() confusion

Tags: java, classloader, contextclassloader

I am new to Java.

I have a requirement to load a configuration file (only one time, at app start up). What is the best way to do this? I have the following ideas:

- `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);`
- `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);`

Out of these two which is the best and why?

Say for example, I have a method like below

```
public void loadConfig(String name) {
    InputStream streamByContextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);
}
```

If I call this method multiple times, is the config file loaded multiple times? Can any Please clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the first approach as it will work in cases when the second approach will not:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
```

I once initially used the second approach in a JUnit test and then we had to change it to use context class loader to allow running the test from IDE.

See: [Difference between thread's context class loader and normal classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader) , particularly this line

*'In this case the object needs to use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() directly if it wants to load resources that are not available on its own classloader.'*

Comment: If I call this Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName‌​); multiple times, is the config file loaded multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Java uses several class loaders during runtime. It would be much simpler to use explicit file declaration instead of resources. Take a look on [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/overview.html#Using_Configuration).

On java class loaders you can read in Oracle [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beadf/index.html). If you pack configuration within your classes (into jar file) - you can use YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...). In other cases - prefer use explicit configuration file.

And yes, multiple calls to getResourceAsStream will load this resource multiple times. To clarify this take a look on java.net.URLClassLoader#getResourceAsStream sources.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a link to apache `Commons Configuration`. But My question is different. If I call this `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);` multiple times, is the config file loaded multiple times?