# Spring Boot: Unable to read resources in lib/*.jar using a class in lib/*.jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath, executable-jar

Iam using spring boot org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher to run my self executable spring boot app jar.

Now, I have my self executable jar packed like this (For brevity Iam just adding the files only that are needed to show the problem):

```
Main.jar   
      ---META-INF
      ---lib
           ---a.jar
              ---com
                  ---comp
                     ---Abc.class
              ---folder1
                 ---1.txt
                 ---2.txt
           ---b.jar
```

and so on.

In my Abc.class Iam trying to load the resource 1.txt which is working fine when I run it in eclipse; but the story starts when I run using command line as self executable jar. I was not able to read that resource and ends up with null pointer error.

After reading few threads, I learnt that my IDEs does some magic on Class Loaders and so it was working fine, which will not be the case when I run it as executable jar

This is how I was Loading the files and the all the possible options I have tried to no luck.

Option 1:

```
Abc.class.getResourceAsStream("\folder1\1.txt")
```

Option 2:

```
Abc.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder1\1.txt")
```

Option 3: Reading [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader), I have tried considered the current thread class loader context as below too, But to no luck again

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder1\1.txt")
```

Can any one advise. How should I write my code to be able to read my resource that is in the jar and by the class that is in the same jar ?

PS: Spring boot is not adding class-path entry to MANIFEST.MF and if I have to do something around that, how do I do that ? In-fact I tried -cp when running my jar setting it to current directory, but that have not worked either

Comment: You should use forward slashes. These are resource names, not Windows filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring, the best way to access a Resource is via [Resource API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)s. For a Classpath resource what you should use a [ClassPathResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) and it would look something like this:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/my/resource.json", this.getClass());
```

After obtaining a `Resource` you can either get a `File` reference via `getFile()` or get an `InputStream` straight off by calling `getInputStream()`.

Spring provides quite a few different implementations of the `Resource` interface, take a look at the list of known implementations in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)

Comment: This worked like Charm. But Iam double confused now, as the class path resource is also doing as below, which is same as what I have been trying

InputStream is;
  if (this.clazz != null) {
   is = this.clazz.getResourceAsStream(this.path);
  }
  else {
   is = this.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(this.path);
  }
  if (is == null) {
   throw new FileNotFoundException(getDescription() + " cannot be opened because it does not exist");
  }
  return is;

What made is different and caused it work ? any clues ?

Comment: Even ClassPathResource doco says:

Supports resolution as java.io.File if the class path resource resides in the file system, but not for resources in a JAR. Always supports resolution as URL.

Comment: The ClassPathResource.getFile() method will work only if the resource points to a file system resource. If you look ac ClassPathResource implementation, in constructor it does some path cleanups as well as a few other things. Later, in the getInpufStream() method it would actually do quite a few checks to cover different cases as well.

Comment: Iam using the direct Constructor with resource and class and calling the getInputStream , I can see getFile being called at all.
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/3.2.14.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.java#ClassPathResource.getInputStream%28%29

Comment: Thank you. Unable to access the ClassPathResource as file and but able to access it as InputStream

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring's class [`ClassPathResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) to load file from classpath.

For example you can read file into String like this from classpath:

```
String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(
       new ClassPathResource("folder1" + File.separator + "1.txt").getFile());
```

It doesn't matter what kind of build tool or project structure you are using as long as that file is on classpath.