# Difference between Thread.currentThread() classLoader and normal classLoader

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader

Can you tell me what is the difference between `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` and `TestServlet.class.getClassLoader()` do not mark it as duplicate and also please explain as well as provide me example when to use these

Java File:

```
package com.jar.test;

public class TestServlet {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        ClassLoader cls = TestServlet.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(
                "com.jar.test.TestServlet");
        ClassLoader cls = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .loadClass("com.jar.test.TestServlet");
    }
}
```

Comment: actually it's a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader/1772346)

Comment: "do not mark it as duplicate" if you know this is a duplicate, then clearly [share your research](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Link to the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and explain how it differs from your question. Meanwhile, I flagged this as a duplicate … (Btw, giving commands such as "do not mark …" can be considered rude.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`**

> Returns the context
>   `ClassLoader` for this `Thread`. The context `ClassLoader` is provided by
>   the creator of the thread for use by code running in this thread when
>   loading classes and resources. If not set, the default is the
>   `ClassLoader` context of the parent Thread. The context `ClassLoader` of
>   the primordial thread is typically set to the class loader used to
>   load the application.

**`Class#getClassLoader()`**

> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use
>   `null` to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return
>   `null` in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader.

---

**In a nutshell:**

[`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader--) is the `ClassLoader` of the context of the thread that has been set with [`setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader cl)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader-java.lang.ClassLoader-). Imagine that you have a complex java application with a hierarchy of `ClassLoader` (for example an Application Server) and you want your current thread to load classes or resources from one specific `ClassLoader` in this hierarchy, you can do it by simply setting the context `ClassLoader` of the thread to this specific `ClassLoader`.

[`Class#getClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--) is simply the `ClassLoader` from which your instance of `Class` has been loaded.

Answer (score 8):

> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()

This is the current thread classloader and doesn't depend on the class calling it

> TestServlet.class.getClassLoader()

This is the classloader that loaded the TestServlet class.

> please explain as well as provide me example when to use these

Let's imagine you have Thread1 owned by ClassLoader1 and Thread2 owned by ClassLoader2. It's possible that you load your TestServlet class on Thread2 (by ClassLoader2) and then pass it to Thread1. At that point, if TestServlet needs to load a Class owned by ClassLoader1 it will need to use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), as it's own ClassLoader is ClassLoader2 and not ClassLoader1.

Comment: Thank all, If possible please provide me some example code so that I can understand better

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it explains why you have to use one instead of the other in some cases.