# Read resource file from inside SonarQube Plugin

Tags: file-io, sonarqube

I am developing a plugin using `org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-plugin-api:6.3`. I am trying to access a file in my `resource` folder. The reading works fine in unit testing, but when it is deployed as a jar into sonarqube, it couldn't locate the file.

For example, I have the file `Something.txt` in `src/main/resources`. Then, I have the following code

```
private static final String FILENAME = "Something.txt";

String template = FileUtils.readFile(FILENAME);
```

where FileUtils.readFile would look like

```
public String readFile(String filePath) {
    try {
        return readAsStream(filePath);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        LOGGER.error("Error reading file {}, {}", filePath, ioException.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

private String readAsStream(String filePath) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)) {
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new IOException(filePath + " is not found");
        } else {
            return IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }
}
```

This question is similar with [reading a resource file from within a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar). I also have tried with `/Something.txt` and `Something.txt`, both does not work.If I put the file `Something.txt` in the `classes` folder in sonarqube installation folder, the code will work.

Comment: Please check that your file is correctly package din your plugin (open the final JAR and ensure the file is at the root). Then `/Something.txt` should work.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam Yes, I checked. The file is already correctly included in the JAR. I opened the JAR, and the file is in the root folder. The code will always have `inputStream` as null if i use both `Something.txt` or `/Something.txt`. The `/`, is it operating system dependent?

Comment: Is it different when using `getClass().getClassLoader()` compared to use `Thread.getCurrentThread().getClassLoader()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/Something.txt").toURI());
BufferredReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String something = IOUtils.toString(reader);
```

Your should not use getContextClassLoader(). see [Short answer: never use the context class loader!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36228195/1838233)