# Reading a WSDL from class path using Thread Context ClassLoader

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am consuminbg a web service and I have places my WSDL in class path inside `WEB-INF/classes` directory. I am running the following code in a tomcat server.

First Approach

```
static {
    URL WSDL_LOC=WSClient.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Data.wsdl");
    System.out.println("Location here is : " + WSDL_LOC);
  }
```

Second Approach

```
static {
    URL WSDL_LOC =   Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Data.wsdl");
    System.out.println("Location here is : " + WSDL_LOC);
  }
```

When I run my war inside of tomcat tyhe first approach prints a `null` on the console while the second console actually prints it right. I just wanted to know why is it so and what is the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my expectation is that the first reference using static reference to WSClient uses the system classloader while the second reference using the current thread is hitting the Web application classloader of tomcat.

Read this link [Difference between thread's context class loader and normal classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader)

Comment: I get that , the only thing I am not sure is why it is returning null

Comment: @station Because the SystemClassLoader is one level above the Webapplication classloader and does not have visibility towards the WAR file contents.

Comment: @station there is one diagram of the classloaders tree, not the accepted answer. It is very good.