# Does loading the same class twice inside same JVM instance happen in this scenario?

Tags: java, classloader

Class B shall be loaded with the same ClassLoader that loaded class A ([proof-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader)).

```
class A {

   B fld = new B();

   void f() {
      B loc_var = new B();
   {

}
```

But **what happens, if class B has already been loaded with a different class-loader before?**

Any class is loaded only once. But classes loaded by different clas-loaders are different classes.

So *class B would be loaded one more time by classloader of class A and two different(!) classes would coexist (within same JVM instance)?*

Comment: So your question is how does the class loader of A know that the class is loaded when it was not the one that loaded it?

Comment: Question is: Is that right that class B would get loaded for the second time (with another classLoader - namely with classLoader which loaded class A)

Comment: No, it only gets loaded once.

Comment: If you’re saying that class B is in the same .jar file as class A, then yes, class B will also be loaded more than once.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of these two ClassLoaders. JVM has three kinds:  Bootstrap ClassLoader, Extension ClassLoader, and Application ClassLoader. When finding a Class, first, JVM will look in Bootstrap ClassLoader, then Extension and Application. So if two ClassLoaders are a different kind, the Class will load only once. If two ClassLoaders are both Application ClassLoader, it will load twice. Which Class is used,  it depends on invoker's ClassLoader.