# Error with classloader in Keycloak and third party lib

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, classloader, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak and some SPI what using different third party libraries.
One of a libs containg some resource files inside of it.
When I'm starting Keycloak, keycloak-server.war calling a SPI my-module.war.

Third party lib (in my-module.war) trying to find resource file by classloader with this line:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

But when this line is executing I get "deployment.keycloak-server.war" classloader instead of "deployment.my-module.war" and module can't find own resource by this wrong classloader.

How can I avoid calling wrong classloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36228195/12051567

What was problem with context classloader.